# gradle commandLine statement blocked by while loop after it

Tags: android, gradle, adb

I have a Gradle task which is meant to start an app installed on a connected Android device. The app is designed to perform some actions and then shut itself down, and my task is supposed to detect this. The app is a Unity-built app, for what it's worth - though I'm not sure it should matter.

Granted, I'm fairly new to Gradle, so please forgive any stupid errors made here.

The task is as follows:

```
task androidTests(type: Exec) {
    def output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    println "Starting Unity Sample App"
    commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', "com.foo.bar/com.unity3d.UnityPlayerActivity"
    while(!output.toString().contains('com.foo.bar')) {
        // Wait for the app to launch
        println "Sample app is not running yet."
        commandLine "adb", "shell", "ps", "yPlayerActivity"
    }
    // Now wait for the app to close
    while(output.toString().contains(packageName)) {
        println "Sample app has not closed yet."
        commandLine "adb", "shell", "ps", "yPlayerActivity"
    }
}
```

Currently, this task does nothing but spam my console with "Sample app is not running yet.", and the app does not launch on the device. The strange this is, if I remove the first `while` loop, the task DOES complete, and the app DOES launch on my device.

Does anyone know what might be wrong here? It seems as if the first while loop is actually blocking the commandLine statement before it, somehow. Any help to figure this out would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: shouldn't you have some sort of delay in your while loops?

Comment: You're not only spamming your console, you're also incessantly spamming adb, could be affecting your ability to communicate with your device over adb. I would try adding a thread sleep of 0.5 seconds in both your loops.

Comment: Actually, before posting this example, I also tried putting a sleep in the loop - of 1000 milliseconds - but it didn't seem to help.